# Identifying Celesta Music

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music

I'm trying to identify a piece of music which I believe is being played on a celesta. I have heard it in several places but can only find a couple of examples. These can be found here at 0:03
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Um_sp2kn9Gc
and here from the start until about 0:57
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=WeJ2MOA4aMc
I've tried Shazam but the music has other audio over it in the examples so it was unable to identify it.

Comment: I'd agree on it being a celeste. The music may just be incidental music for this episode : it sounds that way to me, but hard to be 100% sure.

Comment: @Angst I am almost certain I've heard it elsewhere I just can't remember where, I've even asked friends and they say they know it but can't identify it either. I figured out the first dozen notes on piano but this has yet to help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After over a year of searching I have finally found it - it's called *Sorcerer's Dream* by Paul Mottram. You can listen to it [here](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ks1-7ioBHoQ&t=43s) on YouTube.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an exact match, but it's very reminiscent, probably deliberately, to "[Hedwig's Theme](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Htaj3o3JD8I)" from the *Harry Potter* films (the main title theme), which has the same instrumentation, halting rhythm, and general sense of mystery.

It's quite possibly a "soundalike," a piece of music deliberately composed to evoke another piece of music, but not close enough to violate copyright.

Comment: I have already realised this; in trying to find it I have searched for celesta pieces similar to John William's "Hedwig's Theme" a couple of times but have been unsuccessful and it's driving me crazy!

Comment: @Nemon27 Are you sure that it isn't the similarity to "Hedwig's Theme" that makes you think you've heard it in other places?  Also, if it IS stock music it might well be used in more than one video.